# How to get state of class from another file React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get state of a class from another class but it throws an error "cannot read property 'state' od undefined". My approach is when the user press the button the "FromStr" state get redirect to another class B from A. i tried

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import styles from "./appstyles";
import {getValue} from "./main"

export default class A extends Component{
  constructor (props) {

    super(props)
    this.state={
        From:'',
        FromStr:'',   
    }
  }

 changeText=(From)=>{
  this.setState({From})

 }

 onPress = ()=>{
   this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From})
   this.fetch()
 }
 fetch(){
   getValue();
} 

render(){

return (
<View>
    <View style={styles.inputFields}>
    <TextInput placeholder="From" id="from" style={styles.fromField} onChangeText={this.changeText} />
  <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
  <Button
      title={"Go Back"}
      color="#f194ff"
      onPress={this.onPress}

  ></Button> 
);
}
}

Class B
import React, { Component } from "react";
export function getValue(){
  alert(this.state.FromStr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shared state between components by direct access is an anti-pattern. Each component should have its own state. If you need globally, please consider using Redux.
Passing state as props is also valid, but it only works when components are in parent-child order. Redux allows components to be updated irrelevant of their relationship

As mentioned , pass state as props to their children.

```
class classname2 extends React.Component {
  this.state = { statename1: "lala" };
  render() {
    return <classname1 statename1={this.state.statename1} />
  }
};

class classname1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>{this.props.statename1}</div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define class A's this as global inside it's container. Then, call it from class B. For example;

```
//class A constructor
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    global.__classAThis = this;
}

//class B constructor
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

    console.log(__classAThis);

    //also you can update class A this
    __classAthis.setState({test: true})
}
```

Comment: Very great use of global variable, but passing the complete 'this' of class A to class B affects the performance of the app, right? Is this liable?

Comment: You may store only class state as global variable It's up to you. I am using like above and I did not experience any performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The simplest way is to use `LocalStorage` .

**Usage**

**A screen**

```js
this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From
              }, () => localStorage.setItem('FromStr', this.state.From));
```

**B screen**

```js
componentDidmount(){
  const data = localStorage.getItem('FromStr')
  alert(data);
}
```